# How to generate ppd file for CUPS

Tags: raspbian, cups

I want to add my printer, HP Laserjet Professional M1136 MFP, to CUPS utility on raspberry pi with raspian OS. I have got the relevant printer driver for debian OS from HP website which is a file with .run extension (hplip-3.20.9.run). But I need to provide a PPD file to the CUPS utility. How to generate the PPD file for this purpose?

Note: moving this question from [www.askubuntu.com](http://www.askubuntu.com). There was one answer already provided, which I am pasting below:

> try `sudo apt-get install hpijs-ppds` or `sudo apt-get install hp-ppd`
>
> I just use the 127.0.0.1:631 to config my printers and I don't use HP, so I don't know if these will automatically get populated in your tool.
>
> But I usually end up going through this because my (ubuntu)raspberry pi > cups' driver selection is not filled out with all the drivers I need... > I think also I add foomatic and one other that escapes me (maybe openprinting), until I eventually get what I need...
>
> I generally have to something like `apt-cache search ppd` or `apt-cache search cups` to search what is available.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* find a PPD file from the HP website and install it, but you can usually find what you need with debian.

I use the `hplip` package on Debian with my HP printer.  `hplip` depends on packages such as `cups`, `printer-driver-hpcups` and `cupsfilters` which provide the `/usr/share/ppd/` ppd files.

To configure:

```
sudo apt install hplip
sudo hp-setup
```

`man hp-setup` for some help if you need it.